# How to make an attribute unique for its primary key set without using UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I need to make to make the `Preference` attribute unique for each entry of `(RobberID)`. I can't do this using the `UNIQUE` constraint as there can be several records with the same `Preference`. Is there any way to do this without including it in the primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE info.HasSkills (
    RobberID    INTEGER,
    SkillID     INTEGER,
    Preference  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, --problem (table was created already without UNIQUE)
    PRIMARY KEY(RobberID, SkillID),
    FOREIGN KEY(RobberID) REFERENCES info.Robber(RobberID)
    FOREIGN KEY(SkillID) REFERENCES info.Skills(SkillID)
);
```

EDIT: Is unique only to RobberID, not (RobberID, SkillID).

Comment: What's wrong with a UNIQUE composite key on `(RobberID, SkillD, Preference)`? I mean why do you want to avoid using UNIQUE?

Comment: By this do you mean including Preference in the primary key? I don't want to necessarily avoid using UNIQUE, but when I try to alter my table to make it unique I will get a duplication error

Comment: No I mean creating a UNIQUE key on multiple columns. Check the answers already provided for the syntax. If that doesn't work for some reason, please edit your question with more details on the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. RobberID + SkillID is your primary key. But you say that you "Need to make the Preference attribute unique for each set of (RobberID, SkillID). As RobberID + SkillID is unique there is always only one record for such a set. So how can you get two different Preference for one RobberID + SkillID?

Comment: Sorry I've mixed myself up in the question I will edit now. It is only meant for part of the primary key (RobberID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the `create table` statement as well as by creating an index explicitly (both do the same thing):

```
CREATE TABLE info.HasSkills (
    RobberID    INTEGER,
    SkillID     INTEGER,
    Preference  INTEGER NOT NULL, --problem
    PRIMARY KEY(RobberID, SkillID),
    FOREIGN KEY(RobberID) REFERENCES info.Robber(RobberID)
    FOREIGN KEY(SkillID) REFERENCES info.Skills(SkillID),
    CONSTRAINT unq_RobberId_SkillId_Preference UNIQUE (RobberId, Preference)
);
```

Comment: Cheers this works without 'SkillID' after UNIQUE in the last line, my mistake for asking the question incorrectly

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique index for more then one field.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index1  ON info.HasSkills (RobberID, SkillID,Preference  )
```

So the combination of al three columns must be unique.

Comment: . . A per the comment on my answer, this would work without the `SkillId` in the column list.